# Difference between basis and sub basis of a topological space.

Tags: general-topology

In munkrres there is lemma which says that "each open set in a topology is Union of its basis elements"or in other words we can say that a topology can be generated by Union of basis elements while in case of sub basis it is a subset of basis such that finite intersection and Union of these sets generate the topology....Now my question is that we many times even use finite intersection of basis elements also to generate topology as for example in case of discrete Topology all singletons constitutes a basis for this topology,now if we want to generate ∅ it can always be generated only by taking intersection of any two basis elements.so we used intersection here too,then what's the difference between basis and sub basis?
Hope u understand my question
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> "it can always be generated **only** by taking intersection of any two basis elements..."

That is not true.

If $\mathcal B$ denotes a basis of a topological space then **every** open set can written as: $$\cup\mathcal V:=\bigcup_{V\in\mathcal V}V$$ for some subcollection $\mathcal V\subseteq\mathcal B$, so also the empty set.

If we take $\mathcal V=\varnothing$ then we get: $$\cup\mathcal V=\cup\varnothing=\varnothing$$

So we do not need any intersection for that.

In words: $\varnothing$ can be looked at as *empty union* of sets in $\mathcal B$.

---

If $\tau$ denotes a topology and $\mathcal B$ is a basis of $\tau$ then:$$\tau=\{\cup\mathcal V\mid\mathcal V\subseteq\mathcal B\}$$and (as shown above) then $\varnothing=\cup\varnothing\in\tau$.

This is not true in general if $\mathcal B$ is a subbasis of $\tau$.

Comment: What makes guaranteed that ∅ is in basis ....it might not be there as in case of discrete topology singletons are basis elements but ∅ is not there....

Comment: It is not needed that $\varnothing$ is an element of the basis. It is only needed that $\varnothing$ is a subset of the basis, and of course that is always the case (the empty set is a subset of every set). Then we take union $\cup\varnothing$ i.e. the empty union, and this union is the empty set. If we have e.g. a collection $\{A\}$ then the set of unions of subcollections of $\{A\}$ is $\{\varnothing,A\}$. Here $\varnothing=\cup\varnothing$ and $A=\cup\{A\}$. Note that $\{A\}$ has two subcollections: $\varnothing$ and $\{A\}$.

Comment: Of course ∅ is subset of any set that means ∅ is subset of basis but I need ∅ as a element of basis element and not subset ...... otherwise we wouldn't have any need of ∅ as a element in topology too ..

Comment: Union of basis elements generate topology and not Union of subsets  of basis

Comment: You understand me wrong. Let me try to explain with discrete topology
and basis $\mathcal{B}=\{\{x\}\mid x\in X\}$. Then set $A\subseteq X$
can be written as $A=\cup\{\{x\}\mid x\in A\}=\bigcup_{x\in A}\left\{ x\right\} $,
i.e. a union of basis elements. What happens if we substitute $A=\varnothing$
here? We get: $\varnothing=\cup\{\{x\}\mid x\in\varnothing\}=\bigcup_{x\in\varnothing}\left\{ x\right\} =\varnothing$.
So it is written as union (the empty one) of basis elements. No intersection
was needed.

Comment: Are you familiar with the equality $\cup\mathcal V=\bigcup_{V\in\mathcal V}V$?

Comment: Okay now it's clear.....can u join me on WhatsApp?if u use it...

Comment: How do I do that (joining you on WhatsApp)? I do use WhatsApp, but not so much and have no large familiarity with it.

Comment: U can message me on my number

Comment: +917417642811 my WhatsApp number

Comment: Well, maybe once I will try (so no promisses). Good luck with your study. I am glad that things are clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, a base $\mathcal{B}$ of a topology $\mathcal{T}$ is a collection of *open* subsets of $X$, such that every $O \in \mathcal{T}$ can be written as the union $O=\bigcup \mathcal{B}'$ where $\mathcal{B}' \subseteq \mathcal{B}$.

A subbase $\mathcal{S}$ for that topology is also a collection of open subsets of $X$ such that the set of all *finite intersections" of subfamilies of $\mathcal{S}$ forms a base $\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{S}}$ for $\mathcal{T}$, as defined above. This includes all one-element intersections, so $O \in \mathcal{S}$ can be written as $\bigcap \{O\}$, so $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{S}}$. There is no a priori limit on the number of subbase elements we intersect, except that it is a finite intersection only (otherwise we could have non-open sets in the generated base).

I personally (and many texts agree with me) also include $X=\bigcap \emptyset$ (where $\emptyset$ is seen as a (very) finite subfamily of $\mathcal{S}$) in the generated base $\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{S}}$, but Munkres does not do that and demands from the outset that the union of $\mathcal{S}$ is $X$ already, to avoid the empty intersection explanation (which might be a didactic choice one can defend).

For any base $\mathcal{B}$ we can always write $\emptyset = \bigcup \emptyset$ where $\emptyset \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ so the empty set we get "for free" in the topoloyg generated by a base.